# INSERT INTO ... SELECT

Tags: postgresql

when doing INSERT INTO ... SELECT ... to load data from a table from another one. Does the INSERT start before the end of the SELECT?

example: INSERT INTO films SELECT * FROM tmp_films WHERE date_prod < '2004-05-07';

Comment: Can you explain the reason why you raise that question ? Why it could be of interest to know if INSERT starts before the end of SELECT ? I'm not sure, but I would say NO - INSERT can't start before the end of SELECT, because the SELECT clause has to end so that to know exactly what resulting rows must be inserted, especially when there is an ORDER BY clause and a LIMIT clause in the SELECT.

Comment: Honestly I would say YES. I don't see any reason why INSERT should wait the end of retrieval (If ORDER BY is used, it's the SELECT itself that delays the output)

Comment: Why do you care? The questions has the smell of a [X-Y Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377)

Answer (score 2):

First, the data is collected from the `SELECT` query. Afterwards, this data is given to the `INSERT` statement.

Also check out the docs here: [SQL-INSERT](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html)

Comment: Logically it is processed like that, but technically INSERTing and SELECTing could be done at the same time, because the SELECT won't see any changes to the underlying table while it's running

Comment: Thanks for the hint @a_horse_with_no_name! But doesn't this depend on the isolation level? I think with `Read uncommitted` even data from the current transaction could be read.

Comment: Postgres will never let you read uncommitted data. And even if there were _committed_ changes while the SELECT was running, the SELECT wouldn't see them. Every query will see a consistent view of the database as it was when the query was started - regardless of the isolation level.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I agree with @a_horse_with_no_name, "Every query will see a consistent view of the database as it was when the query was started". If table t is 50Gb, all 50Gb must be kept in a temporary space until INSERT starts?

Comment: @FabriceChapuis: no, see the description of the [MVCC implementation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/mvcc-intro.html) in the Postgres manual